# Closures in Golang - String not displayed

Tags: go

I have been following lot of Tutorials on `Closures` in `golang`, but still couldn't really achieve the below one

I have a function named 'greeting' that takes the `name` as the input and  has a `closure` within it, which would give the full-greeting message

```
func greeting(name string) func() string {
    fullGreeting := ""
    return func() string {
        var message = "Welcome to Closures " + name
        fullGreeting = message
        return fullGreeting
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(greeting("Arun"))
}
```

Am expecting it to print `Welcome to Closures Arun`while it is printing just the method-value `0x48b660`

Comment: `greeting("Arun")` is a function and those do not get called by magic. Add `()`.

Comment: I understand now.. It returns a `function` and it needs to be called with `()` .. I understand now.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the main function with

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(greeting("Arun")())
}
```